# Getting into object oriented PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to lean object oriented PHP. It works but I doubt that it is really oo ;-)

My problem is that I have this beautiful class `Weintyp` that creates an input field. However, to check if the form has been sent, I need to check the variable `$gesendet_we`. Now, I have this beautiful method in my class, but I get an error if I try to use `$_GET["$gesendet_we"]` as a variable, because it is not set. I solved this by checking with `isset()` before, but it seems like cheating. How can I do it right?

Here my classes:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

abstract class AbstrakteFunktionen
{

    public function IstLeer($var)
    {
    $wert = empty($var);
    return $wert;
    }

}

class Formular extends AbstrakteFunktionen
{
    public $gesendet;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->gesendet = 0;
    }

}



class Objekt extends AbstrakteFunktionen
{
    public $anzeigename;
    public $laenge;
    public $feldname;
    public $groesse;
    public $idname;
    public $tabelle;
    public $wert;
    public $typ;
    public $gesendet;


    public function EigenschaftenAusgeben()
    {
    echo 'Anzeigename: ' . $this->anzeigename . '<br>';
    echo 'L&auml;nge: ' . $this->laenge . '<br>';
    echo 'Feldname: ' . $this->feldname. '<br>';
    echo 'Gr&ouml;&szlig;e: ' . $this->groesse . '<br>';
    echo 'IDName: ' . $this->idname . '<br>';
    echo 'Tabelle: ' . $this->tabelle . '<br>';
    echo 'Wert: ' . $this->wert . '<br>';
    echo 'Typ: ' . $this->typ. '<br>';
    echo 'Gesendet: ' . $this->gesendet . '<br>';
    }

    public function FehlerFeldLeer($gesendet) // nur für Pflichtfelder
    {
    if (isset($gesendet) AND $gesendet = 1)
        {echo ' Hinweis: Bitte ' . $this->anzeigename . ' eingeben!';}
    }

}


class Weintyp extends Objekt
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->anzeigename = "Weintyp";
    $this->laenge = 58;
    $this->feldname = $this->anzeigename;
    $this->groesse = 100;
    $this->idname = $this->feldname . "id";
    $this->tabelle = "ktbl_". $this->anzeigename;
    $this->typ = "text";
    }

    public function IstEingabeLeer()
    {
    $wert = empty($_GET["$this->feldname"]);
    return $wert;
    }


    public function EingabeEinlesen()
    {
    if ($this->IstEingabeLeer() == FALSE)
        {
                $this->wert = $_GET["$this->feldname"];
        }
    }

    public function EingabefeldErzeugen()
    {
    echo    '<b>' . $this->anzeigename . '</b> <br> <input size="' . $this->laenge . '" maxlength= "' . $this->groesse . '" type="' . $this->typ .
            '" name="' . $this->feldname . '" value="' . $this->wert . '">';
    }

    function ergebnisAusgeben()
    {
        return $this->ergebnis;
    }


}

?>
```

Here my Code:

```
<?php

// Globale Variablen und Funktionen laden
require_once('functions.php');
require_once('classes.php');

$EingabefeldWeintyp = new Weintyp();
$EingabefeldWeintyp->EigenschaftenAusgeben();

if  ($EingabefeldWeintyp->IstEingabeLeer())

    { // Formular erzeugen

        echo '  <h2> Weintyp erfassen </h2>
                <form>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="linkspflicht">';

        $EingabefeldWeintyp->EingabefeldErzeugen();
        if(isset($_GET['gesendet_we']))
        {$EingabefeldWeintyp->FehlerFeldLeer($_GET['gesendet_we']);}

        echo '      </div>
                </div>';

                echo '  <input type="hidden" name="gesendet_we" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="navigation" value="weintyp_erfassen_oo">
                        <input type="hidden" name="nleiste" value="daten">
                        <br>
                        <p> <input type="submit" formaction="index.php" value="Weintyp erfassen" /></p>
                            </form>';

    }

    else 

    {
        echo 'Was anderes';
    }

?>
```

Comment: FWIW, it’s really good habit to do your code in english. Especially, if otherwise not possible for some dummy reason, translate them for SO, so we can read the code with more ease :)

Comment: also, with PHP, you need to use `isset()` with *everything*. no exceptions. (well, with all data you can’t be sure the value is present)

Comment: Just some variable and method names are in German but the problem independent of that ;-)

Comment: In that case, I don’t think the code snippets serve any purpose :)

Comment: Well of course I know I have to use it with everything... I just want to know if I violate some oop paradigms and how to do it better! It feels so wrong to check in plain code instead of inside a class!

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking still, but in case you want your whole code reviewed, there is stackexchange just for that ^^ for SO, I think you should only attach the relevant part of question, with names that people can easily understand it.

Comment: I don't understand the question/problem (even though I understand German). You have a form and want to know if the form has been sent - so `isset()` seems good. Alternatively you could use a class to construct the form and have it containing an attribute `sent` that does exactly the same.

Comment: Ok well my problem is just that I want to do it right, to write good code that I can pass on to my grandchildren. I am new to OOP, so I am not sure if this is good enough.

Comment: Okay, in that case, this should be really go to code review SE site... I’m going to flag this as so :)